# Using \IfNoValueTF within a TikZ style specification.

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfplots, conditionals, xparse

In an answer to [Flushing PGF commands and local variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17228/flushing-pgf-commands-and-local-variable) Matthew had suggested using `\IfNoValueTF` within a TikZ `\node` specification to determine the text. This solution works great for me.

However, I would also like to able to have these type of conditions within the style without having to define a temporary style. So, in the following, I would like use `LabelPointZ` to be to determine the style to be used, just as the working `LabelPointY` determines the text without having an intermediate variable.

```
\documentclass{articles}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\LabelPointY}{o o m m g}{
  \addplot [#1] coordinates{(#3,#4)} 
    node [#2]
        {\IfNoValueTF{#5}{$(#3,#4)$}{#5}};
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\LabelPointZ}{o g m m g}{
  \addplot [#1] coordinates{(#3,#4)} 
    node [\IfNoValueTF{#2}{color=red,right}{right, #2}]
        {\IfNoValueTF{#5}{$(#3,#4)$}{#5}};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    %\LabelPointZ[mark=*,color=red]{0.2}{0.2}
    %\LabelPointZ[mark=*,color=red][color=green]{0.3}{0.3} 
    \LabelPointY[mark=*,color=red][color=blue, below right]{0.5}{0.5} % default label
    \LabelPointY[mark=*,color=red][color=blue, below]{1  }{1  }{top}  % given label
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't use the `minimal` class for minimal working examples. It is not intended for this even when the name might suggest it. There is no reason to use it and it might cause issues because it only defines a minimal set of macros and has some common lengths set to zero.

Comment: @Martin: The first document linked to in the FAQ answer to http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/231#231 uses this class, which might make people think it's the appropriate thing to use. Maybe you could incorporate your comment into the FAQ?

Comment: @Jake: Thanks for pointing this out to me. That document also states quite at the beginning: "You may need to substitute
the minimal class with another commonly available class, such as `article`,
`report` or `book`." I better add some note to the FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having some code in the styles, even expandable ones, doesn't work well.
Just move the `\IfNoValueTF` out from the TikZ style:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\LabelPointZ}{o o m m g}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
    \addplot [#1] coordinates{(#3,#4)} 
        node [color=red,right]
  }{%
    \addplot [#1] coordinates{(#3,#4)} 
        node [right, #2]
  }%
        {\IfNoValueTF{#5}{$(#3,#4)$}{#5}};
}
```

This has however the drawback that you have to write some code twice.

Alternatively use the `/utils/exec` key to execute the `\IfNoValueIF` switch and use then `\tikzset` to set the styles. It looks quite funny but works stable.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\LabelPointZ}{o o m m g}{
  \addplot [#1] coordinates{(#3,#4)} 
    node [/utils/exec={\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\tikzset{color=red,right}}{\tikzset{right, #2}}}]
        {\IfNoValueTF{#5}{$(#3,#4)$}{#5}};
}
```

Comment: I have been using a solution similar to your first example. But, can't find out exactly what `/utils/exec` is, so have [posted a follow up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17834/what-is-utils-exec-and-where-do-i-find-its-documentation) as it might be useful to others as well.

Comment: @Peter: It is a PGF/TikZ key so it is documented in the PGF/TikZ manual. It can be found by a simple search in the PDF. Like I wrote it simply executes the given code.