# What is `/utils/exec` and where do I find it's documentation

Tags: documentation

In response to [this question on using a conditional to define a TikZ style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17643/using-ifnovaluetf-within-a-tikz-style-specification) it was suggested to use `/utils/exec`.

It is easy to find uses of this, but I have not been able to locate documentation on it. I have looked in the TeXbook and TeX By Topic, but did not find this.

So, where what exactly is `/utils/exec` and where can I find documentation on it. Under what conditions should one use this or not use this?

Comment: See Section 55.4.8 **Handlers for Key Inspection** of the pgfmanual.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Could you make that an answer.

Comment: It is a PGF/TikZ style so it is of course in the `pgfmanual`. You wont find such things in the TeXBook or in TeX By Topic, they list only plainTeX macros but not (La)TeX packages.

Comment: I didn't realize it was a PGF/TikZ style and hence it wasn't obvious to me where to look. Hopefully this will be of help to someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is implemented by [`PGF/TikZ`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf); see Section 82.4.8 **Handlers for Key Inspection** of the pgfmanual.